# How to add a button to the upper left corner of TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a C# 2.0 WinForms application, looks like this

[image: my current project]

How to add a button to the upper left corner of TabControl, looks like this?

[image]

I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: I can't suggest code, but it is not possible without creating your own version of the `TabControl`, by deriving from it or recreating it altogether.  It's not a standard functionality that users would expect.

Comment: You can tinker the with RightToLeft properties, it is not ideal.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kieren Johnstone said it's not possible without creating your own version.. But you could actually just add a tab to the control and catch the on tab changed event. Get the currentTab and if it matches the one that should be your button execute said code.. Then change back to the previous tab.... Its more than possible just a little different.

If you hide the tab it will shift the entire tab control to the left effectively taking out the space you are trying to achieve.. If you do it like what I am saying. And simply add a tab to the tab control. Then use that tab as your button, It will work just like a button does just a little code behind is required to first get the event when the user clicks a tab in the tabControl.

First set the current tab index to the one you want the user to be defaulted to. Store the index value in a variable. Now catch the tabchanged event.  If the first tab is selected then the user has clicked your intended button thus meaning you should fire your code that you would have fired from an actual button. Next change the selectedTabIndex to the value contained in the index variable you set earlier. If the first tab is not selected update the value of the index variable set earlier.. This is the simplest way around your problem that I can think of off hand.

Comment: yes Kieren Johnstone was right. I've tried nobugz suggestion http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c290832f-3b84-4200-aa4a-7a5dc4b8b5bb . Hide the first tab, and then add the button to empty area at the upper left corner of tabcontrol. but how can i hide ONLY The First Tab? Does hiding the first tab will give empty space at the upper left corner? Thank you